# Convert user selected JSON file to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to convert a `.json` file to an object. So to do this, I use this function:

```js
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
      callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
JsonForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  readTextFile("codebeautify.json", function(text) {
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

But how do I convert the file that the user selected?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? `JSON.parse(text)`

Comment: Not actually. I choose file from code. But i want to do that form input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i done that by myself.

```
 function onChange(event) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = onReaderLoad;
                    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
                }

                function onReaderLoad(event) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
                    const JsonForm = document.querySelector('#JsonForm')
                    JsonForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        UploadJson(obj)
                    });
                }

                function UploadJson(value) {
                    value.forEach(function (obj) {
                        var today_date = new Date();
                        value.forEach(function (obj) {
                            db.collection('...').add({
                                addate: today_date,
                                nickname: obj.nickname,
                                points: obj.points,
                                prize: obj.prize,
                            }).then(() => {
                                 console.log("Document successfully added")

                           }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err)
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
                document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

//usage

```
                    <form id="JsonForm">
                         <input type="file" accept=".json" id="file">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API instead. This promise returns the result that has a native [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method.

```js
JsonForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch('codebeautify.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
});
```